# How do I go about printing only the first letter of name in capslock along with the following?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, uppercase

a.  Ask the user to enter their first name. The user may enter the name using uppercase or lowercase letters.

b.  If the name starts with a vowel, print the message ‘Your name starts with a vowel.’; otherwise print the message ‘Your name starts with a consonant.’

c.  Print the first letter of the name in uppercase, along with a suitable message. This part should be executed for all cases, whether the name starts with a vowel or consonant.

What I have done:

```
name = input('Enter your name:')
first = name[0]

if first == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
print("Your name starts with a vowel")

else first
print("Your name starts with a consonant")

print('The first letter of your name is:', name.upper[0])
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT
[image]

Comment: `name[0].upper` not `name.upper[0]`

Comment: If you want to get "Jack" out of "jack", "JACK" or even "jAcK", use the `.title()` method.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just have some python syntax wrong. Try this:

```
name = input('Enter your name:')
first = name[0]

if first.upper() in 'AEIOU':
    print("Your name starts with a vowel")
else:
    print("Your name starts with a consonant")

print('The first letter of your name is:', first.upper())
```

Comment: Without solving the WHOLE thing, since it's clearly an assignment ... the above won't work for names such as "Arun", "Edgar", "OLAV" ... but hopefully John can see why and devise a fix himself!

Comment: Thanks for the help the correct code is:                                                  
elif first != 'aeiou':
    print("Your name starts with a consonant")

Comment: John, I don't think that solves the problem glennji was alluding to ;)

Comment: I edited my answer, for completeness sake (see the if statement change), but please make sure you understand why!

Comment: Because we need to take into account if the user inputs the first letter of the name in capslock?

Comment: Yep, you got it! :)